# Avoid type casting in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following situation:

```
const data = {
  bmw: 10,
  opel: 2
}

type customType = keyof typeof data

const myKey = 'bmw';

console.log(data[myKey as customType])
```

Doing this `data[myKey as customType]` i want to access the key from `data`. I read that using `as` we use `type casting` and this is not very safe.

**Question**: How to rewrite the code above avoiding the use of `as` operator?

Comment: Out of curiosity want to understand why using as is not a safe operation?
Also as data is already of specific type, we can just access the key and if that key doesn't exists then it should through compile time error.

Comment: @Bkjain655, i read that `as` is like you bound typescript to assert a type. But it exists another way to type the code above instead using `as`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles perfectly well if you simply *remove* the typecast. Like so:

```
const data = {
  bmw: 10,
  opel: 2
}

type customType = keyof typeof data

const myKey = 'bmw';

console.log(data[myKey])
```

This is because you have defined `myKey` as a const variable, which means it has the type `bmw` (since it can never change) which is assignable the index type of `'bmw' | 'opel'`

Comment: But it exists another way to type the code above instead using `as` ?

Comment: The code is already typed. You don't need to use anything...

Answer (score 1):

just define your variable as `customType`:

```
const data = {
  bmw: 10,
  opel: 2
}

type customType = keyof typeof data

const myKey: customType = 'bmw';

console.log(data[myKey])
```

or directly:

```
const myKey: keyof typeof data = 'bmw';
```

specifying that `myKey` is of type `customType` will ensure that you can put only `bmw` or `opel` as a value, otherwise will produce compilation error; therefore is slightly "safer" than "as".